# Are Dark Souls 2 player ghosts realtime?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Are Dark Souls 2 player ghosts (*the ghosts you encounter in bonfires and the ghosts you encounter while running around in the world*) **realtime**, or are they just recorded actions of other players online and merely **playbacks**?

*(Nobody ever warcries back to me...)*

Comment: I don't think you could fight a playback of actions. In racing games, any actions ghosts make are relative to the track. Making a ghost fight with patterns relative to the enemy involves keeping track of waaaaay to many things.

Comment: @user1337 You don't fight player ghosts in Dark Souls 2, you can't even interact with them. You just see them moving around.

Comment: @DominicDeCoco Oh, I think I recall what ghosts he means. Think that's what I saw in some playthroughs. (Never played DS myself). Somehow I was thinking of invaders and stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ghosts are in fact real time, look at this [video](http://youtu.be/woftolOQjt0?t=2m26s) for evidence of this. I have also been able to communicate through the emotes with a ghost before (or maybe it was just a freaky coincidence)

**Note** This is Dark Souls 1 but like the other people have stated I don't see why they would change things.

Answer (score 2):

I have waved and been waved back at by a ghost in DS2. I've also had one running around in me in circles whilst I was running down a bridge. which was weird.

Answer (score 0):

The random ghosts that pop around and at bonfires are reportedly real, however I can find no record of this being confirmed. For instance, [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/216flp/when_you_see_another_players_ghost_doing_their/) some people mention that they "-have seen a couple phantoms flinch when I come around the corner at them...".

The reason it's interesting is that this could be an example of synchronous multiplayer OR it could be just an advanced little gimmicky AI that is just meant to trick you into thinking that they're real players.

Comment: There's actually no question that the ghosts are real players, they have been in Demon's Souls and Dark Souls 1 and there would be no point in changing that for 2. The same goes for the bloodstains and that's why you don't see them in offline mode. The question is, however, if the movement happens at exactly the same time as your own or if they just playback the other player's movement of e.g. 10 minutes ago.

Comment: I'm sorry! My answer wasn't too explicit in explaining that I guess.  The part where I  mention that someone noticed they flinch and also in the link someone says they were cheered on by a phantom argue that it is at the same time, but there is no official answer for this.

Comment: In the Fog area with nearly invisible NPCs, I have had Player Apparitions try and fight me, mistaking me for the NPCs

Answer (score -1):

Yes they are. I was helping my friend and I saw his ghost apppear and walk to my summon. Three seconds later I was summoned by him.